# Visual Studio 2015 - Erro de extensão

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Sempre que eu abro o meu Visual Studio 2015, me dá essa mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o log que a mensagem aponta:

> ERROR Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same
>   ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop' is already loaded at
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON
>   FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\10\DESKTOP SDK...
>             C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\   Extension Manager 2017/07/07 12:28:02.937  526
>   ERROR Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same
>   ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore' is already loaded
>   at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON
>   FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\10\WINDOWS STORE SDK...
>             C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\8.1\WINDOWS STORE SDK\   Extension Manager 2017/07/07
>   12:28:02.937  527 ERROR Error updating the registry for incompatible
>   extensions. Exception: A task was canceled.   Extension Manager

Answer (score 1):

Por algum motivo, uma extensão foi instalada mais de uma vez.

Isso parece ser um problema comum. [A solução mais abrangente que encontrei está no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743381/visual-studio-2012-crash-after-installing-visual-studio-2013). Desconsidere a *tag* utilizada lá, pois o problema é do VS e não da linguagem. Segue aqui uma tradução:

- Vá ao painel de controlo;
- Selecione o Visual Studio;
- Selecione as opções para alterar/modificar, até alcançar a janela onde pode modificar as extensões do Visual Studio;
- Utilize a janela para remover as extensões em conflito. No caso específico desta pergunta, provavelmente deverão ser desinstalados os kits de desenvolvimento para *desktop* e para *Windows Store*, pois ambos apresentaram conflitos (não se trata do primeiro a conflitar com o segundo - são realmente dois erros).
- Confirme tudo e reinicie o computador.

Se isso não resolver, talvez seja necessário desinstalar outras extensões.

Se o Visual Studio abrir corretamente após esses passos, você poderá tentar instalar as extensões novamente, seguindo os mesmos passos acima.